# How to copy files to a Linux server from ASP.NET with permissions problems?

Tags: .net, linux, samba

My question is more about how to overcome a permissions problem.  There is an Apache application that creates a new folder each time a new employee is added.  I am working on an application that can copy files into each of these folders.  Unfortunately, the folders are created with write permissions only for the owner (Apache Daemon).

I am currently trying to accomplish this using Samba.  I don't have access to the Apache application, but have full access to change anything on the server.  However, I can't write into these directories even when connecting as root through Samba.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is samba rewriting permissions to a specific user? Even if you connect as root, samba could be using some other non-root account for the actual file operations.

Comment: It must be because I can create files directly from the server as root.  How would I check that?

Comment: dig around in samba's config file (/etc/samba/smb.conf most likely?) and see if.  look for `force user` and `force group` options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had removed the read only = Yes option, not realizing that it was still the default.  Added writeable = Yes.